# How can I use the struct library in python to pack a double into two uint32's

Tags: python, numpy, struct, pack, unpack

So this is what I would like to do:
I have a double and I need to pack it into binary data and then get the upper four bytes and store them into a uint32 (it has to do with a device driver).

I already do this with floats:

```
import struct
import numpy as np
tmp = struct.pack('<f',float(datatobeconverted))
dataout = np.uint32(struct.unpack('<I',tmp))
```

I would like to do this with doubles but It doesn't seem to work:

```
tmp = struct.pack('<d',double(datatobeconverted))
dataout0 = np.uint32(struct.unpack('<I',tmp[0:3]))
dataout1 = np.uint32(struct.unpack('<I',tmp[4:7]))
```

Any ideas? By the way, I think the way struct stores binary data is unintuitive and hard to read

Comment: Instead of saying 'it doesn't work', show us the error message.

Comment: You might not think the way `struct` stores data to be stupid if you understood the computer architecture a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just slicing `tmp` wrong.

```
>>> dataout0 = np.uint32(struct.unpack('<I',tmp[0:3]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4
>>>
```

The error message is pretty clear: the string arg you're passing is **not** "of length 4".

Python slices are always "right-bound **excluded**".  So, to slice off the first 4 bytes, you do:

```
>>> dataout0 = np.uint32(struct.unpack('<I',tmp[:4]))
```

The `0:` in `0:4` is optional, and it's best to avoid it, as a matter of style, to minimize clutter (Tufte's "no wasted pixels" principle).

Similarly, to get everything **but** the first four bytes,

```
>>> dataout1 = np.uint32(struct.unpack('<I',tmp[4:]))
```

Left-bound is *included*, so you can use the same value (here, `4`) for both slicings (one of the advantage of the right-bound-excluded concept, helping you avoid off-by-one errors).

I first met this principle decades ago in Koenig's still-awesome book "C traps and pitfalls" and I have lived by it since -- and the principle's consistent adoption is part of what me love Python at first sight:-).

(I believe some kind of slicing on `pandas` frames is the one exception to this principle throughout widespread Python libraries -- and part of why I can't get whole-heartedly into `pandas`... but, that's another story!-).

Answer (score 1):

`np.dtype` can perform the same sort of repacking

```
np.array(struct.unpack('II', struct.pack('d', double(np.pi))), dtype='uint')
# array([1413754136, 1074340347], dtype=uint32)

dt1 = np.dtype((double, {'a':(np.uint32,0),'b':(np.uint32,4)}))
np.array([np.pi], dtype=dt1)[['a','b']]
# array([(1413754136L, 1074340347L)], dtype=[('a', '<u4'), ('b', '<u4')])
```

Answer (score 0):

`unpack` creates a tuple, which you need to either unpack or index to get individual values, even if you are only unpacking a single value. You can use a single call to `unpack` to get both values at the same time.

```
tmp = struct.pack('<d',double(datatobeconverted))
data0, data1 = struct.unpack('<II',tmp)
dataout0, dataout1 = np.uint32(data0), np.uint32(data1)
```